# Triggering csv import for RavenDB from the command line

Tags: csv, import, ravendb, ravendb-studio

I was wondering if it is possible to integrate the csv import into a powershell/bash script (even if that means doing something with curl or friends). Essentially, what is achieved by the clicks on "Choose file" and "CSV Import" in Ranorex Studio - just "script style".
I couldn't find anything in the docs or here...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.
See this documentation topic:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/client-api/how-to/integrate-with-excel

Basically, you generate a URL and instead of using Excel to fetch it, you use curl or something similar.

Comment: I am trying to get data INTO RavenDB, not out of it. In RavenDB Studio: Tasks => CSV Import. I am going to try and find out what's going on with Wireshark/Fiddler and see if I can emulate the call.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Yes, that would be the easiest way to do so.

Comment: Thanks Ayende. I'll post an answer once I have something workable.